# wait for Asynchronous web service call response to process next web service ios

Tags: ios, web-services, asynchronous

Currently I am working on an application in which I have 8 Asynchronous web service call in sequence.
To get a response I use delegate method.
Response of web service call contains "Id" field which I need to pass in consecutive web services.
Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You tried anything ?. After getting response of first webservice, parse the data and fetch the id. Then call the next webservice with that id and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your reply and time.
In my scenario I have solve my question using simple 1 bool variable.
And I have array containing web service methods name which were called through a method.
I have follow below steps:
1) take a bool variable and set that to false.
2) Call first web service, remove the object for first web service method from array and return from the method and wait for the response.
3) When I get the response, where I got the "Id", first I check for the bool variable to false. If so update the bool variable and make it true. And recall the method containing array of web service call method.

Answer (score 0):

Try block in objective C using following code

```
 -(void)getResponse:(NSString *)url AndWithCallback:(void(^)(BOOL success, id responseObject))callback{
       if(data != nil){
           callback(YES,@"Your object");
       }
       else{
           callback(NO,@"pass nil");
       }
    }
```

Invoke Method :

```
[self getResponse:@"your url" AndWithCallback:^(BOOL success, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
       if(success){
       // call another webservice
       }
```

}];

from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40178081/3901620